# Linear Algebra: Find the distance from the point $Q(2,2)$ to the line $ L$ whith parametrization $[x,y] = [-1,2] + t[1,-1]$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is asking to find the distance from the point $Q(2,2)$ to the line $L$ whith parametrization $[x,y] = [-1,2] + t[1,-1] $.

So first I find a point $A$ that lies on the line. From the equation of the line given, I know that $[-1,2]$ is a point that lies on the line. I know this because the vector form equation of a line is $x = p + td $ where $p$ is a point on the line.

Then I find the vector $QA$ , by taking the difference of the coordinates of $A$ and $Q$v. From this I get $[-3,0]$ .

Then I find the projection of $QA$ onto $d$ ($d$ is the directional vector for line $L$). I know $d$ is $[1,-1]$ from the equation of the line provided, so finding the projection of $[-3,0]$ onto $[1,-1]$ gave me $[-3,3]$ .

Lastly, the distance between the point $ Q $and a point on the line $L$, which I'll call $P$ , is found like so: 
$QP = QA$- (projection of $ QA$ onto $ d$)

And the result I get is $ [0,-3]$ . But my textbook says that's not correct.

Could someone maybe do the question or tell me where I went wrong? Also, apologies for not formatting this properly, this is my first post and I'm not sure how to.
 Any help whatsoever is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Now as to your question, the distance should be a *number* so surely $[0,-3]$ isn't the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we can consider the segment

$$QA=(-3+t,-t)$$

and use the condition of perpendicularity with the direction vector of the line that is

$$QA\cdot v=0 \implies -3+t+t=0 \implies t=\frac32$$

therefore

$$QA=(-3/2,-3/2) \implies |QA|=\frac32\sqrt 2$$

By your method note that te projection of $a=(-3,0)$ onto $b=(1,-1)$ is given by

$$a_\perp=\frac{a\cdot b}{b\cdot b}b=(-3/2,3/2)$$

and then

$$a_\parallel=a-a_\perp=(3/2,3/2)$$

Comment: I see! That does make sense, thank you. However I'd also like to see it done with the method I described, because that method should work as well, no? Would it not be possible to do it with the method I described?

Comment: @JamesRonald Yes of course, I'll try to elaborate that!

Comment: @JamesRonald It seems to me that your mistake is the projection of $(-3,0)$ onto $(1,-1)$, it can't be $(-3,3)$. Can you see why?

Comment: Really sorry for the late response, just wanted to say thanks so much for the help! Yes, seeing you do it made me realize that mistake (not sure how I did that in the first place haha...). Also I hadn't seen that other method you used but it's certainly much easier. 

Just one last quick question: in your first method, how did you know that QA = (-3+t, -t)? I'm not sure how you knew to have that specifically just from the coordinates [-3,0]. How did you choose +t and -t, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: the direction vector for the line is $a=(1,-1),\ $ so $a_p=(1,1)$ and therefore, choosing the convenient point $(-1,2)$ on $L$, we note that the distance from $Q$ to $L$ is the scalar projection of the segment $\overline {(2,2)(-1,2)}$ onto $a_p$, which is given by $\frac{a_p\cdot ((2,2)-(-1,2))}{\|a_p\|}=\frac{(1,1)\cdot (3,0)}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Comment: Hmm, unless I'm doing my math wrong, 7/√2 doesn't seem to equal (3*√2)/2, which is what my textbook says is the right answer.

Comment: Yes, I miscalculated the vector difference. It should be OK now. Thanks.